# Schema.org validating pages inconsistently

Tags: google-search, schema.org, google-rich-snippets

I have a website that uses the same template for several different hotels. Each hotel has the same schema layout (as per the template), but a google search for "hotel name" + phone number produces inconsistent results.

Sometimes the name of the hotel is included below the phone number, sometimes not. Has anyone else seen this inconsistency with schema.org? I have tested the pages out on https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/ and everything seems to be uniform.

Comment: this doesn't appear to be enough to work from, inspect the DOM from a working and a non-working hotel and post here. It could also be down to caching on google's servers, or the localization,  eg fr.google.com vs google.com for France

Comment: @Mousey the markup is consistent from one hotel to the next. The schema was added a year ago, so it's unlikely it's a caching issue. Is there any way to get google to recrawl the schema?

Comment: Check how often it crawls with your sitemap, and use Fetch as Google to re-crawl, it seems to pick up structured data a few days after that. Are the hotels which have the problem in the same country as the hotels which are ok, and is the country specified? Google says it does not guarantee to display the results in a specific way, but usually it does.

Answer (score 0):

When did you publish the new template including the Schema.org markup?
--> Give Google some time to crawl / cache your data.

Besides that, I observed similar behaviour with other websites:
--> Even for website using the same template for several described entities (in general) Google sometimes shows this markup in the search results or simply ignores it.

Comment: The schema was added a year ago, so it's unlikely it's a caching issue. Is there any way to get google to recrawl the schema?

Comment: @symlink Fetch as Google, submit, then wait a few days.